# Getting values with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I started learning javascript a few weeks ago, the problem is that with my code I don't get the values that I put and I don't find where the problem could be.

```
function muestraDatos(){
    var var1=document.getElementById("clogin").value;
    var var2=document.getElementById("cpassword").value;
    var var3=document.getElementById("cemail").value;
    var var4=document.getElementById("cnombre").value;
    var var5=document.getElementById("capellido").value;
    var var6=document.getElementById("cfecha").value;
    var var7=document.getElementById("cedad").value;
    var var8=document.getElementById("ccolor").value;
    var var9=document.getElementById("ccalle").value;
    var var10=document.getElementById("ccpostal").value;
    var var11=document.getElementById("cpoblacion").value;
    var var12=document.getElementById("cprovincia").value;
    var var13=document.getElementById("ctelefono").value;
    var var14=document.getElementById("csemestre").value;
    var var15=document.getElementById("ccarrera").value;
    var var16=document.getElementByName('cinteres').value;
    alert("Login: "+var1+"\nPassword: "+var2+"\nEmail: "+var3+"\Nombre: "+var4+" "+var5+"\nFecha de nacimiento: "+var6+"\nEdad: "+var7+"\nColor preferido: "+var8+"\nCalle: "+var9+"\nCódigo postal: "+var10+"\nPoblación: "+var11+"\nProvincia: "+var12+"\nTeléfono: "+var13+"\nSemestre: "+var14+"\nCarrera: "+var15+"\nInterés: "+var16);
}

<form onsubmit="return muestraDatos()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Solicitud socio</legend>
    <label>Login: </label>
    <input type="text" id="clogin" />
    <br/>
    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="text" id="cpassword" />
    <br/>
    <label>Email: </label>
    <input type="email" id="cemail" />
    <br/>
    <strong>Datos personales:</strong>
    <br/>
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" id="cnombre" />
    <br/>
    <label>Apellido: </label>
    <input type="text" id="capellido" />
    <br/>
    <label>Fecha de nacimiento: </label>
    <input type="date" id="cfecha" />
    <br/>
    <label>Edad: </label>
    <input type="number" min="18" max="100" step="1" value="18" id="cedad" />
    <br/>
    <label>Color preferido: </label>
    <input type="color" id="ccolor" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Contacto</legend>
    <label>Calle: </label>
    <input type="text" id="ccalle" />
    <br/>
    <label>Código postal: </label>
    <input type="text" id="ccpostal" />
    <br/>
    <label>Población: </label>
    <input type="text" id="cpoblacion" />
    <br/>
    <label>Provincia: </label>
    <input type="text" id="cprovincia" />
    <br/>
    <label>Teléfono: </label>
    <input type="tel" id="ctelefono" />
    <br/>
    <strong>Datos estudiante:</strong>
    <br/>
    <label>Semestre </label>
    <select id="csemestre">
      <option value="semestreP">primero</option>
      <option value="semestreS">segundo</option>
    </select>
    <label>Carrera </label>
    <select id="ccarrera">
      <option value="disenyo">diseño</option>
      <option value="arquitectura">arquitectura</option>
      <option value="derecho">derecho</option>
      <option value="otra">otra</option>
    </select>
    <br /> Interés
    <br/>
    <label>Pintar</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cinteres" value="pintar" />
    <label>Hacer deporte</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cinteres" value="hacerdeporte" />
    <label>Ver peliculas</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cinteres" value="verpeliculas" />
    <label>Escuchar musica</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cinteres" value="escucharmusica" />
    <label>Leer</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cinteres" value="leer" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Step one: Go and learn to make use of your browser's JS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78pg8jpt/)

You had a typo here in this line

```
 var var16 = document.getElementByName('cinteres').value;
```

It's actually

```
 var var16 = document.getElementsByName('cinteres').value;
```

You missed an 's' in `getElementsByName`.

Also, according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName), `document.getElementsByName`

> Returns a nodelist collection with a given name in the (X)HTML
>   document.

Thus, your code needs to be replaced as

```
var var16 = document.getElementsByName('cinteres')[index].value;
```

where index is the index position of the nodelist that is returned.

Comment: _"It's actually `var var16 = document.getElementsByName('cinteres').value;`"_ - that still won't return anything useful. getElementsByName returns a NodeList, so the individual items in the that list need to be addressed individually, f.e. via their index.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, and thankyou for pointing out..updated the answer... :)